# In C, does a pointer to a structure always point to its first member?

Tags: c

Suppose I have a number of C structs for which I would like a particular set of functions to operate upon.

I'm wondering if the following is a legitimate approach:

```
typedef struct Base {
     int exampleMember;
     // ...
} Base;

typedef struct Foo {
     Base base;
     // ...
} Foo;

typedef struct Bar {
     Base base;
     // ...
} Bar;

void MethodOperatesOnBase(void *);

void MethodOperatesOnBase(void * obj)
{
     Base * base = obj;
     base->exampleMember++;
}
```

In the example you'll notice that both structs `Foo` and `Bar` begin with a `Base` member.

And, that in `MethodOperatesOnBase`, I cast the `void *` parameter to `Base *`.

I'd like to pass pointers to `Bar` and pointers to `Foo` to this method and rely on the first member of the struct to be a `Base` struct.

Is this acceptable, or are there some (possibly compiler-specific) issues I need to be aware of? (Such as some sort of packing/padding scheme that would change the location of the first  member of a struct?)

Comment: Any reason why you don't just use C++?

Comment: Yes. But point well taken. I am trying to imitate a super-simple inheritance mechanism for a limited number of structs in my project.

Comment: Then use C++. It'll make things just as simple, you'll be able to avoid any UB pitfalls, and you'll be able to extend the class hierarchy later with ease if you need to.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I can't for this project.

Comment: Why can't you? Is this homework? Are you working in an environment where C++ is not available? What's the logic here?

Comment: `Is this homework?` Been out of school for 10 years, but thanks. LOL

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: It's a legitimate question. Suppose your program is 10,000 lines long and written in C. Then you have like about 100 lines of where you need to do this struct-punning. In that case, it's probably worth it to use a bit more effort to keep the entire program compatible in C.

Comment: Or maybe the reason ain't that. :) I didn't say the question was invalid but it helps to know the context for a question like this.

Comment: @Mysticial is close to accurate. Except 10,000 lines is an underestimate. Closer to 100,000 - plus peripheral applications with interop libraries (for .NET, Java, and Obj-C). Existing build and deployment scripts/processes. Etc. Switching languages just isn't in the cards right now.

Comment: Changed the title to something more descriptive (and easier to google for), if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre! That *is* much better.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, the C standard specifically guarantees that this will work.

> (C1x §6.7.2.1.13: "A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member ... and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within as structure object, but not at its beginning.")

Comment: @MByD: the standards themselves are not linkable for silly copyright reasons, but Google can find several drafts for you.

Comment: 6.7.2.1.15 in the committee draft: C11 standard found here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The whole gtk+ is implemented like that. I cannot think of a better example. Take a look at http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not disagreeing with any of the answers saying that what you suggested will work, but in the interests of a more complete discussion (without suggesting you use C++!), why not do something like

```
typedef struct Base ...  /* The types defined exactly as before */
typedef struct Foo ...
typedef struct Bar ...

/* The function takes a Base* since that is what it actually works with*/
void MethodOperatesOnBase(Base* pbase)
{
    /* Do something... */
}

/* Now call it like this: */
Foo foo;
Bar bar;

MethodOperatesOnBase(&foo.base);
MethodOperatesOnBase(&bar.base);
```

Is there some reason that won't work and you need to use `void *`? I don't see that this is much more work and it does have the advantage of type-safety.

Comment: Well, In my particular case, the reason is because `Foo` and `Bar` are being exposed as opaque pointers.

Comment: @ Steve: OK, so the caller isn't able to make the reference to the `base` member and you have to do it by reinterpreting the struct pointer. That makes sense, thanks for clarifying.