# Double pointer and single pointer from void *?

Tags: c, pointers

I was reading a book about implementing OOP in C and found this code :

```
void delete (void * self)
{ 
    const struct Class ** cp = self;
    if (self && * cp && (* cp) -> dtor)
        self = (* cp) -> dtor(self);
    free(self);
}
```

I want to know why the author had created a double pointer rather than a single pointer
like this

```
void delete (void * self)
{ 
    const struct Class * cp = self;
    if (self && cp && cp -> dtor)
        self = cp -> dtor(self);
    free(self);
}
```

Is there any difference ?

Comment: For that you probably have to go back in the book, to where the author discusses the design, because we can't possibly know about the intentions of the author.

Comment: Also, check how this `delete` function is called. If it's passed the address of a pointer (e.g. `&pointer`) then the second version will crash and burn.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, it well crush, but you night as well pass `pointer` instead of `&pointer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the author's object system, each object struct contains as its first element a pointer to its class:

```
typedef struct Object1 {
    Class *myclass;
    int data;
} Object1;

typedef struct Object2 {
    Class *myclass;
    double data;
} Object2;
```

That means that by treating a `void *` pointer to any object as a `Class **` pointer, the class pointer can be followed without knowing the actual type of the object.  This is allowed by the standard, because:

> [c11](/questions/tagged/c11)
>
> #### 6.7.2.1 Structure and union speciﬁers
>
> 15 [...] A pointer to a
>   structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. [...]

So any pointer `Object1 *` or `Object2 *` etc. can be converted to a pointer to its first element i.e. `Class **` (since the first element of either is of type `Class *`, a pointer to the first element is of type `Class **`).  See [In C, does a pointer to a structure always point to its first member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312555/in-c-does-a-pointer-to-a-structure-always-point-to-its-first-member) for more information.

This is a legal approach, but a little difficult to follow.  An equivalent would be to write

```
typedef struct BaseObject {
    Class *myclass;
} BaseObject;
```

and require that each object struct contain a `BaseObject` instance as its first member; the `delete` function would then cast `self` to `BaseObject *` and write `((BaseObject *) self)->myclass->dtor`:

```
void delete (void * self)
{ 
    BaseObject *base = self;
    if (self && base->myclass && base->myclass—>dtor)
        self = base->myclass->dtor(self);
    free(self);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the non protable sentence? In what regard is it not portable? OS? Compiler?

Comment: Sorry, I'm incorrect; it is allowed.  6.7.2.1:15 *A pointer to a
structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.*

Comment: Just wondered if I was writing unportable code on daily basis for years ;) - without even knowing.

Comment: In the delete example that you have given at the end, you are not using "base" but "self". Is it right ?

Answer (score 1):

In this system each object contains a pointer to its class in the first field. Effectively, `Class **c = self` gets the class structure from the object instance.

Answer (score 0):

Becuase of the struct design:

```
*(const struct Class **)p=class;
```

in there:
http://humelab.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3/trunk/ooc/new.c

as seen in the

```
void * new(const void *_class,...)
{
 const struct Class *class=_class;
 void *p=calloc(1,class->size);
 assert(p);
 *(const struct Class **)p=class;  //<------look here!

 if(class->ctor)
 {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap,_class);
  p=class->ctor(p,&ap);
  va_end(ap);
 }
 return p;
}
```

Comment: why am i not being able to do it like:  const struct Class **pt = (const struct Class **) p; *pt = clas; is it "const struct *" ? then why C allows it to be changed like this in a line?

Comment: Is this a good design ? Am i reading the right from right source ?