# Why use address of first element of struct, rather than struct itself?

Tags: c, struct

I've just come upon yet another code base at work where developers consistently use the address of the first element of structs when copying/comparing/setting, rather than the struct itself.  Here's a simple example.

First there's a struct type:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} foo_t;
```

Then there's a function that makes a copy of such a struct:

```
void bar(foo_t *inp)
{
    foo_t l;
    ...
    memcpy(&l.a, &inp->a, sizeof(foo_t));
    ...
}
```

I wouldn't myself write a call to `memcpy` in that way and I started out with suspecting that the original developers simply didn't quite grasp pointers and structs in C.  However, now I've seen this in two unrelated code bases, with no common developers so I'm starting to doubt myself.

Why would one want to use this style?

Comment: None of the answers below actually added anything to my knowledge of C, which sort of was what I was hoping for ;)

Comment: This is pretty useful specifically when multiple types of struct start with the same first element, as a sort of pseudo-inheritance. The CPython codebase uses this heavily with `PyObject`; all Python objects start with a `PyObject` member, and they're usually passed around with `PyObject *` pointers so you don't have to hardcode the actual type of the object you're working with.

Comment: The `memcpy` becomes safe if this is the final argument: `sizeof(foo_t) - offsetof(foo_t, a)`.

Comment: I did stuff like this a fair bit when I was first getting the hang of C structs and arrays. I'd guess your belief as to why it was happening was pretty much spot-on.

Comment: I would start by not having a single letter variable named `l`.

Comment: A "what does the standard say" version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312555/in-c-does-a-pointer-to-a-structure-always-point-to-its-first-member

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Nobody should do that. 
If you rearrange struct members you are in trouble.

Answer (score 62):

Instead of that:

```
memcpy(&l.a, &inp->a, sizeof(foo_t));
```

you can do that:

```
memcpy(&l, inp, sizeof(foo_t));
```

While it can be dangerous and misleading, both statements actually do the same thing here as C guarantees there is no padding before the first structure member.

But the best is just to copy the structure objects using a simple assignment operator:

```
l = *inp;
```

*Why would one want to use this style?*

My guess: ignorance or bad discipline.

Comment: +1 for best `l = *inp`.  Suggested distant 2nd best `memcpy(&l, inp, sizeof l)`.

Comment: ignorance? Not so sure... I mean, they *knew* (hopefully) that the two things were equivalent and guaranteed by the specification so I don't think you can infer *lack* of knowledge from that code, but only a *bad use* of such knowledge (which if often worse!).

Answer (score 16):

One wouldn't.  If you ever moved `a` in the struct or you inserted member(s) before it, you would introduce a memory smashing bug.

Answer (score 12):

This code is unsafe because rearranging the members of the struct can result in the `memcpy` accessing beyond the bounds of the struct if member `a` is no longer the first member.

However, it's conceivable that members are intentionally ordered within the struct and programmer only wants to copy a subset of them, *beginning* with member `a` and running until the end of the struct.  If that's the case then the code can be made safe with the following change:

```
    memcpy(&l.a, &inp->a, sizeof(foo_t) - offsetof(foo_t, a));
```

Now the struct members may be rearranged into any order and this `memcpy` will never go out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is one legitimate use case for this: constructing a class hierarchy.

When treating structs as a class instances, the first member (i.e. offset 0) will typically be the supertype instance... if a supertype exists. This allows a simple cast to move between using the subtype vs. the supertype. Very useful.

On Darren Stone's note about intention, this is **expected** when executing OO in the C language.

*In any other case*, I would suggest avoiding this pattern and accessing the member directly instead, for reasons already cited.

Answer (score 2):

It's a really bad habit.  The struct might have another member prepended, for example.  This is an insanely careless habit and I am surprised to read that anyone would do this.

Others have already noted these; the one that bugs me is this:

```
struct Foo rgFoo [3];
struct Foo *pfoo = &rgFoo [0];
```

instead of

```
struct Foo *pfoo = rgfoo;
```

Why deref the array by index and then take the address again?  It's already the address, the only difference of note is that pfoo is technically

```
struct Foo *const,
```

not

```
struct Foo *.
```

Yet I used to see the first one all the time.