# Why are *curr and curr->val the same value?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Consider:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node item;

void main() {
    item * curr, *head;
    int i;

    head = NULL;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));

        curr->val = i;
        curr->next = head;
        head = curr;
    }

   curr = head;
   while (curr) {
        printf("%d\n", curr->val);
        printf("%d\n", *curr);
        curr = curr->next;
   }

   getchar();
}
```

---

As I print out, `*curr` and `curr->val` are the same. Why?

I am confused about `*curr`. I think `*curr` is the value `&curr` points to. (I am newbie in C.)

Comment: If you are compiling with warnings, the line "printf("%d\n", *curr);" should print a warning since struct node is not an integer. While there is a reason you see this behavior, it's a bit complicated and has to do with how varargs are handled in C. Probably you should just avoid doing this so that the behavior is more understandable.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", *curr);` is undefined behaviour because `*curr` is not an int.

Comment: In addition to the what the above comments correctly pointed out, for reference, accessing elements with  `(*curr).val` is same as `curr->val`

Comment: `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘item’ [-Wformat=]  printf("%d\n", *curr);`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597425/are-struct-names-pointers-to-first-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776731/why-use-address-of-first-element-of-struct-rather-than-struct-itself .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, does a pointer to a structure always point to its first member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312555/in-c-does-a-pointer-to-a-structure-always-point-to-its-first-member)

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Try `printf("%d %s\n", cur->val, "hello")` vs `printf("%d %s\n", *curr, "hello");` if you think they're the same.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here

```
curr->val = i;  
curr->next = head;
head = curr;
```

first you set `(*curr).val` to `i`. Then you make `curr->next` point to `head`. At this time still `NULL`. Then you make `head` point to `curr`. And here the interesting part, `curr` points to its beginning and `*curr` dereferences it which is essentially `curr->val`, because from there starts the struct `curr`.

As per Standard and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312555/in-c-does-a-pointer-to-a-structure-always-point-to-its-first-member)

> (C1x §6.7.2.1.13: "A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member ... and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within as structure object, but not at its beginning.")

Which means that there isn't any space (padding) (or also e.g. some `HEAD` information) between the actual structure start and the start of its first element.

EDIT:
I don't say anything about UB, not because I don't see it. OP asked for something else. It should be pointed out, but not be THE answer! That's why we have Comments Section!

Comment: `curr` does point to `&(curr->val)` but `*curr` is **not** `curr->val` it just starts with `curr->val` but it is longer. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 9):

First as a beginner, you should try to write correct code that raises no warning before trying to understand what happens under the hood and why some incorrect expressions still give correct results.

C is a very permissive language, that is as long as the compiler can translate what it reads it generally assumes that the programmer knows why he wrote it. It's what happens here.

In C, the address of a `struct` can be cast to an address to its first element. So `(void *) &curr` is the same as `(void *) &(curr->val)`. Here I cast everything to `void *` to make sure to have compatible pointer types.

That means that `*((int *) curr)` is a perfectly defined C expression and its value is indeed `curr->val`. But it is correct, because I wrote an explicit pointer cast.

What you wrote *works* only by accident, because as `curr` is an aggregate type; you pass an `int` and an `item *` to `printf` and use only its first value - this is **no longer** standard C and I can only assume a *classic* implementation to guess that. But just replace your print commands by that:

```
printf("%d - %d\n", curr->val, 12);
printf("%d - %d\n", *curr, 15);
```

You should see garbage in the second `printf`, because with `%d` you declare that you pass a simple `int` and actually pass an aggregate. Here again, nothing is explicitly mandated per standard, but common implementation should give this result.

**TL;DR:** As `*curr` is not an `int`, `printf("%d\n", *curr);` is Undefined Behaviour. This means that anything can happen, even the expected result, but a different version of same compiler, or another compiler, or even a change in compilation parameters could give a different result, as could a minor change in the code.

And C allows automatic pointer cast to and from `void *` and you should never cast the return value of `malloc` as it can hide bugs. Please write:

```
curr = malloc(sizeof(item));
```

It is no longer C++ compatible, but is it correct C.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behaviour and will give you warnings.

`printf` gets the type of argument being passed to it with the help of format specifiers. In your case the first element of the structure is a `int`and hence has a `int` at the top of the stack. Hence when `printf` looks for a `int` it finds one and gives the correct output, even though you passed the entire structure.

If there was any other data type than `int` as the first element of your structure, it would have given an undefined output.
Hence as I mentioned in the comments, the correct ways to access the structure elements are with `(*curr).value` or as you have used `curr->value`.

Comment: You say that the code is undefined behavior, but later say that "if there was any other data type than `int`... it would have given an undefined output". Surely if it's undefined behavior the output is already undefined, no matter the type?

Comment: @PaulHankin True, I wrote that just to clarify about the correct output in this case, and how it will not carry for other cases.