# C programming ( structs)

Tags: c

I am have one question. Lets say we have a struct which is defined as follows:

```
 typedef struct test { 
   int x;
   int y;
 };
```

Now if I create a instance of this struct as follows;

```
  test object;
```

So will the " &object == &object.x "??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312555/in-c-does-a-pointer-to-a-structure-always-point-to-its-first-member

Comment: You probably meant `typedef struct { ... } test;`. This is not related to the question you asked (which has been answered since), but it's generally a good idea to post actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the address of the first data member of the structure will be equal to the address of the object of the structure itself.

From the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units
>   in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order
>   in which they are declared. **A pointer to a structure object,
>   suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is
>   a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.**
>   There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.