# Is this technique of "struct inheritance" guaranteed to work, or is it implementation dependent?

Tags: c, struct

Please consider the following code:

```c
typedef struct {
    int base_value;
} Base;

typedef struct {
    Base base;
    int child_value;
} Child;

Base* base = get_thing();
Child* child = (Child*) base;
```

Is the following guaranteed to *always work*, or is it implementation-dependent?

```c
printf("%d", child->base_value);
```

Please note I'm *not* going through `base` first (`child->base.base_value`), but going directly to `base_value`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C, does a pointer to a structure always point to its first member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312555/in-c-does-a-pointer-to-a-structure-always-point-to-its-first-member)

Comment: It is guaranteed to never work. `Child` does not have a member called `base_value`.

Comment: the type `Child` does not have a member called `base_value` so the line `printf("%d", child->base_value);` does not compile because you have casted it to type `Child`. There are other problems too. The actual object is a `Base` but since you casted it to `Child` the compiler will treat it as `Child` so you could try to access `child->base` or `child->child_value`. The actual object is type `Base` so accessing `child_value` is UB in every implementation.

Comment: It generally makes more sense to cast `Child*` to `Base*`, not the other way around.

Comment: An exception is when calling a "Factory" method.

Comment: Since you've not shown how `get_thing()` is written, it is not possible to know whether it allocates enough space for a `Child` or whether it only allocates enough space for a `Base` (or, indeed, whether it allocates anything, or returns a valid pointer to anything).  This is why an MCVE ([MCVE]) is important.  Missing details often matter.